# OpenLayers clear path on marker movement

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 6.

I would like to produce behaviour like on Google Maps:

When the marker has passed the point, all previous points should be hidden and the only route that is left to pass should be visible.

For example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

So when I start marker animation, I would like the previous **yellow** route that marker passed to be hidden, and only route ahead of him should be visible

Is that even possible?

Comment: With some coding this is possible. Are you really using OL 2?

Comment: @TomazicM I'm using OL 6, could you help me, could you provide me with same example or some api methods I could use ?

Comment: @TomazicM Could you show me how ?

Comment: In this example https://jsfiddle.net/xe270r3j/ the blue line is fixed and a new red line is produced as the marker moves.

Here https://jsfiddle.net/587kutpv/ is the the same code modified so the red line runs from the marker to the end of the route.

The markers move more smoothly along the route than the in the OpenLayers example as their position is based on calculated distance instead of index of vertices (where the marker moves much faster on straight sections where vertices are further apart).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve desired effect of clearing the route behind the moving marker in mentioned example, all you have to do is to modify `moveFeature` function, so that at each marker move new route geometry is created that contains only points not covered yet by the moving marker.

Code could then look something like this (just three lines inserted):

```
var moveFeature = function (event) {
  var vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(event);
  var frameState = event.frameState;

  if (animating) {
    var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now;
    var index = Math.round((speed * elapsedTime) / 1000);

    if (index >= routeLength) {
      stopAnimation(true);
      return;
    }

    var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[index]);
    var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);
    vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, styles.geoMarker);

    // three new lines
    var remainingRouteCoords = routeCoords.slice(index);
    var remainingRouteGeom = new ol.geom.LineString(remainingRouteCoords);
    routeFeature.setGeometry(remainingRouteGeom);
  }
  map.render();
};
```